# Setting XHR requests header runs the backend twice in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Here's the my front Ajax code

```
let ii = 0
function dothisone(e) {


  e.preventDefault();

  ii++

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = true;

  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
      console.log( this.responseText);
      console.log('Ajax ran: ', ii, 'Times');
    }
  });

  xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


  xhr.send();

  console.log('You hit the button: ', ii, 'Times');
}
```

And here's my backend code in node js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

let numt = 0;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

numt++;
   
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',

    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'content-type, Accept, Authorization',

    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': false,

  });
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var txt = q.year + " " + q.month;
  console.log('Backend got',numt,'hit(s)');

  res.end(txt);
}).listen(9000);
```

console.log for every single request / button clickin my backend hits twice and shows

```
// first request
Backend got 1 hit(s)                                                                                                                                        
Backend got 2 hit(s)
// another request
Backend got 3 hit(s)                                                                                                                                        
Backend got 4 hit(s)
```

This only occurs every i set this(or any othe header before sending) in the xhr request

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

please help!!!
I'm using pure node js. No frameworks please. Thanks

Comment: The first one is a preflight request and the second one is the regular request.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Musa How do I dinstiguish between both in my App? What do I have to do..?

Comment: The preflight request is an OPTIONS request as oppose to the POST you're sending